# Python - Truncate a timestamp in json array

Tags: python, json, timestamp, truncate

Giving the following json array:

```
[
{
    "2020-02-03T00:04:11.000Z": {
        "USD": [
            0.38449135,
            422507.831002123,
            0
        ]
    },
    "2020-02-04T00:04:08.000Z": {
        "USD": [
            0.39151832,
            390909.273872433,
            0
        ]
    },
    "2020-02-05T00:04:16.000Z": {
        "USD": [
            0.40914842,
            498653.042530699,
            0
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to remove the minutes, seconds and milliseconds of the key value.

As you can see, the key values are different per item.

Result should be:

```
[
{
    "2020-02-03": {
        "USD": [
            0.38449135,
            422507.831002123,
            0
        ]
    },
    "2020-02-04": {
        "USD": [
            0.39151832,
            390909.273872433,
            0
        ]
    },
    "2020-02-05": {
        "USD": [
            0.40914842,
            498653.042530699,
            0
        ]
    }
]
```

Additionally, it should be great if the "USD" key could be deleted and the 3 values will move directly to the first level of the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One liner below

```
data = [
    {
        "2020-02-03T00:04:11.000Z": {
            "USD": [
                0.38449135,
                422507.831002123,
                0
            ]
        },
        "2020-02-04T00:04:08.000Z": {
            "USD": [
                0.39151832,
                390909.273872433,
                0
            ]
        },
        "2020-02-05T00:04:16.000Z": {
            "USD": [
                0.40914842,
                498653.042530699,
                0
            ]
        }
    }
]
short_data = {k[:k.find('T')]: v['USD'] for k, v in data[0].items()}
print(short_data)
```

output

```
{'2020-02-03': [0.38449135, 422507.831002123, 0], '2020-02-04': [0.39151832, 390909.273872433, 0], '2020-02-05': [0.40914842, 498653.042530699, 0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the key by `T` as a separator.

Please consider the next code:

```py
import json



start = [
{
    "2020-02-03T00:04:11.000Z": {
        "USD": [
            0.38449135,
            422507.831002123,
            0
        ]
    },
    "2020-02-04T00:04:08.000Z": {
        "USD": [
            0.39151832,
            390909.273872433,
            0
        ]
    },
    "2020-02-05T00:04:16.000Z": {
        "USD": [
            0.40914842,
            498653.042530699,
            0
        ]
    }
}
]


def process_data(data):
    result = []
    for k in data:
        result += data[k]
    return result

result = []
for item in start:
    new_dict = {}
    for dct_item in item:
        data = process_data(item[dct_item])
        truncated = dct_item.split('T')[0]
        if truncated in new_dict:
            new_dict[truncated] += data
        else:
            new_dict[truncated] = data
    result.append(new_dict)

print(json.dumps(result,indent=4))
```